# Installing and loading "rJava"

Tags: rjava

I am encountering problems loading the "Deducer" package due a loading problem with "rJava". The installation of "rJava" seems to be done correctly, yet it fails when calling it to load.

Please, can anyone shed some light of wisdom? :)

Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: stop("No CurrentVersion entry in '", key, "'! Try re-installing Java and make sure R and Java have matching architectures.")
  error: object 'key' not found
Error: package/namespace load failed for ‘rJava’

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On xubuntu 12.04 with javac 1.7.0_21 set as default via:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives
```

then

```
$ sudo R CMD javareconf
$ sudo R
> update.packages()
```